# Redirect user that tries to view malicious URL or one that is not on the snort rule list?

Tags: snort

I have a fairly simple inline IPS set up that is using Snort as the detection system. I was wondering if it is possible with Snort to redirect a user that tries to view a URL that is on a disallowed list.

I'm subscribed to the Snort live-updated/most recent database and it is working and giving me alerts, but the only thing I have seen so far on the topic of redirections is to go:

Malicious attack -> Snort recognizes attack -> redirected to honeypot, and not:

User on LAN -> snort recognized disallowed site -> redirects to xyz page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snort's [*replace*](http://manual.snort.org/node34.html#SECTION00479000000000000000) keyword in a rule to replace the disallowed URL with a URL of your choosing.  The only qualifications when using the keyword is the new text must be the same length as the previous text.

You can also use the [*react*](http://manual.snort.org/node26.html#SECTION003114000000000000000) keyword to respond with an html page of your choice, but that will block the connection too.